# update a nested dictionary with values of a list

Tags: python

Need to iterate the list values in the nested dictionary

```
d = { 'a' :{'a': '3','b': '2 '},'b':{'c':'1'}}

temp = (20,31,111,455,55,6)

for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        for k in temp:
            d[i][j]=k

print d
```

I expect the following:

```
d = { 'a' :{'a': '20','b': '31 '},'b':{'c':'111'}}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that dicts are fundamentally *not ordered*. While the current implementation means they keep an order, that's not part of how they're intended to work. It doesn't make sense, conceptually, to expect a result like this, because there is nothing to say that the `'b'` key comes "after" `'a'` in the `d` dict, or vice-versa. You need to be more clear about exactly what you are trying to do and, more importantly **why**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = { 'a' :{'a': '3','b': '2 '},'b':{'c':'1'}}

temp = (20,31,111,455,55,6)
count=0
for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        #update nested dictionary value
        d[i][j]=temp[count]
        #increment count variable
        count+=1

print(d)
```

O/P:

```
{'a': {'a': 20, 'b': 31}, 'b': {'c': 111}}
```